# Use variable in mysql CL

Tags: mysql, shell

Is it possible to use shell variable in a mysql query via command line?
What I want to do is :

```
$ var='test'

$ mysql -e 'INSERT INTO table (text) VALUE ($var);' database
```

It didn't seems to work, even when I use `${var}`

Any idea of how I can do something like that?

I have to stay in the shell, as I am running this through a **jenkins 'execute shell'**

Comment: You need to double-quote the outer SQL string for the variable to be expanded, and you need to single-quote `'$var'` inside the SQL because it is a string literal. See [When to use single quotes, double quotes, backticks](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11321508/541091)  <-- That is in context of PHP, but almost the same situation with a shell.

Comment: What is the source of the variable `var`? If it results from some other command's output as opposed to hard-coding a variable, you may have to worry about SQL injection or at the very least, proper escaping so it does not break the SQL statement.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski
Yes, my problem was all a quotes problem, and I manage to fix it.
The 'var' source was a command > reading a json file.
In the end what I wanted to do didn't work out, json file was loosing it's quotes. And so I moved to an other solutions than doing a mysql request. thanks any, it was good knowledge

Comment: You should post an answer below with what became your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, with the help of the comment, I finally manage to do it.

The link [explanations of quotes in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks/11321508#11321508) explain everything.

The solution :

```
$ var='test'
$ mysql -e "INSERT INTO table (text) VALUE ('$var');" database
```